# c# Using GeckoFx 14 How to get started?

Tags: c#-4.0, geckofx

I am looking at this site : https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-14.0

I don't know anything about GeckOFX, so downloading the the zip file I make references to Geckofx-core-14 and Geckofx-WinForms-14.

I use the this code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;
using GeckoFX;

namespace GeckoFXTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("C:\\tools\\xulrunner");
            GeckoWebBrowser myBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
            this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
            myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            myBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

But I think I am missing something, can someone tell me what I am missing? OR how to get started, I can't find docks for GeckOFX 14

Using C# WinForms 4.0 .Net
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line you have commented out is important:

```
//Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("C:\\tools\\xulrunner");
```

You need to download xulrunner 14 or firefox 14 and tell geckofx where to find it, by calling Gecko.Xpcom.Initialze before creating the GeckoWebBrowser control.

Also you only need to call Xpcom.Initialize once per application so you prolly don't want to put it in your Form Constructor.

Comment: Is there something else I have to install? I am just totally guessing on how to set it up, I have no instructions and it seems that I am missing something..

Comment: ok I think I found where to download it..  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/  anything else that I need?

Comment: Please notice that Xpcom.Initialize schould be call only once per application - it makes "Program.cs" a good point to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can download xulrunner-sdk
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-33.0/downloads

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Gecko;
    using Gecko.DOM;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Net.Mime;
    using System.IO;
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(@"F:\bak\Desktop\frefox c sharp\xulrunner-33.1.1.en-US.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\bin");

            }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://example.com");


            }
}
```